# VBA Excel, Updateing pivot

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 pivot tables on 2 sheets in over 30 files so i tried to use vba to update them automatically. Problem is that i get an error 438. I don't know why it appears. My code:

```
 Sub update()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim SrcData As String
    Dim pvtCache As PivotCache

Sheets("Raw Data").Select

  SrcData = ("Raw Data") & "!" & Range("$A$9:$M$100000").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

Sheets("Cost Week_Month").Select'This contain 2 tables, the same source data
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache (pvtCache)

Sheets("View Week_Month").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").ChangePivotCache (pvtCache)

End Sub
```

Comment: Set break on all errors then at least you can find out what line the error happens on

Comment: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache (pvtCache) this line

Comment: Which one you have two lines like that. Are you sure you have a PivotTable1 on both sheets?

Comment: the first one, error 438 object does't support this property or method

Comment: When you're creating the PivotCache, the sourcetype = `xlDatabase`. According to [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194688%28v=office.14%29.aspx) "The ChangePivotCache method can only be used with a PivotTable that uses data stored on a worksheet as its data source. A run-time error will occur if the ChangePivotCache method is used with a PivotTable that is connected to an external data source." Is your source data within the Excel workbook?

Comment: Yes it is. There are 3 worksheets: Raw Data, Cost Week_Month, View Week_Month. Raw Data contains data which goes to pivots which are in cost week month and view week month

Answer (score 1):

It's probably this line:

```
SrcData = ("Raw Data") & "!" & Range("$A$9:$M$100000").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

You're telling it to use R1C1 reference style, but supplying a "LetterNumber" reference.

Comment: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache (pvtCache) this line is makeing problems

Comment: I would have dropped the `ReferenceStyle` parameter, but in either case, this doesn't seem to be the source of the problem.